# Extracting boolean terms from Z3 model when using quantifiers

Tags: z3, smt, cvc4

I am trying to use Z3 to explore the difference between two predicates, but the model contains `exist`-expressions where I would expect boolean constants.

I have the following program in smtlib:

```
    (set-option :produce-models true)
    (declare-fun a (Int) Bool)
    (declare-const t1 Bool)
    (declare-const t2 Bool)
    (assert (= t1 (exists ((i Int)) (and (a i) (or (= i 10) (= i 11) )))))
    (assert (= t2 (exists ((i Int)) (and (a i) (and (< i 13) (< 9 i))))))
    (assert (distinct t1 t2))
    (check-sat)
    (get-value (a))
    (get-value (t1 t2))
```

I am trying to find the values for `t1` and `t2` when the problem is satisfiable.

Z3 responds with

```
    sat
    ((a (store (store ((as const Array) true) 11 false) 10 false)))
    ((t1 (exists ((i Int)) (and (not (= i 10)) (not (= i 11)) (or (= i 10) (= i 11)))))
     (t2 (exists ((i Int))
      (and (not (= i 10)) (not (= i 11)) (not (<= 13 i)) (not (<= i 9))))))
```

The model for `t1` and `t2` does not give me boolean constants, but expressions. How can I persuade Z3 to give me the values of these expressions? (I believe the model for `t1` is actually a contradiction, so it is always false.

I don't need to do this through smtlib, using the Z3 api would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get a value for top-level values. And a simple `exist` (i.e., one that's not nested) is equivalent to a top-level declaration. (There are ways to deal with nested exists as well, via skolemization, but that's besides the point.) So, simply pull those exist-variables to the top:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun a (Int) Bool)
(declare-const t1 Bool)
(declare-const t2 Bool)
(declare-const i1 Int)
(declare-const i2 Int)
(assert (= t1 (and (a i1) (or (= i1 10) (= i1 11) ))))
(assert (= t2 (and (a i2) (and (< i2 13) (< 9 i2)))))
(assert (distinct t1 t2))
(check-sat)
(get-value (a))
(get-value (i1 i2))
(get-value (t1 t2))
```

This prints:

```
sat
((a (store ((as const Array) true) 12 false)))
((i1 10)
 (i2 12))
((t1 true)
 (t2 false))
```

I believe this satisfies all your constraints and gives you the values of `t1` and `t2`, along with `i1` and `i2` that make them distinct as requested.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Out of curiosity, what's the definition of "top-level values"? What makes `t1` and `t2` in my original code not top-level?

Comment: Your `t1` and `t2` are top-level; but not `i1` and `i2`; and those are crucial for getting the model you were after. So, I just pulled them to top-level. (i.e., your `exists i` declarations.)